# Build path problems with sdk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I just downloaded the Android SDK and the plugin but when I try to create a project it automatically makes a library for the support and my project that I created has errors. Here is what I mean:
[image: error]
[image: tree]

This is after I clean up the projects [Project -> Clean]

[image: error]
[image: tree]

Additionally, R does not work (even when I import it) :
[image: code]

This is all with a clean project. I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Note: I know there are similar questions out there, but I could not get it working.

I think I need to import the appcompat package again, but I do not know where to locate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error the container "Android Dependencies references non existing library" probably means your build path isn't pointing to any jar file. I recommend checking your build path:

Right click and choose 'build path'

Click on 'Android'. Make sure app_compact appears under the library target. If it does not click 'add' under library to add it.

Comment: didn't help. just checking answer for rep.

Comment: Also, is the 'is library' button checked in that section? if not check it.